# Customize knowledge article layout in Communities?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities, salesforce-service-cloud

`I would like to customize the article type layout that is used when a Knowledge article is viewed in a community.

I know how to do this for the standard Knowledge interface in Salesforce, but not in communities.  Can anyone point me to documentation or let me know how to get started?

I am create lwc component and aura also but they did not show on community.
`<target>lightningCommunity__Page</target> <target>lightningCommunity__Default</target> <target>lightningCommunity__Page_Layout</target> <target>lightningCommunity__Theme_Layout</target>`
I added this in lwc xml file`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.